# как сделать наложение блоков html

Tags: html, css

Верстаю данный шаблон, и не получается сделать наложение блоков как на фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:

```css
body {
    background-color: #101114;
}
    
.datainfo {
    width: 350px;
    height: 236px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e9ee;
    left: -240px; top: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
    
.cvc {
    width: 370px;
    height: 236px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e9ee;
    background-color: #f7f8f8;
    margin-top: -57%;
    margin-left: 55%;
}
    
.line {
    width: 269px;
    height: 42px;
    background-color: #e4e9ee;
    margin-left: 27.5%;
    margin-top: 26px;
}
    
.cvc_code {
    width: 138px;
    height: 42px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e9ee;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 57%;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
    
.form {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;
    width: 639px;
    height: 569px;
    background-color: #f7f8f8;
}
    
.info, .numberpay, .sumpay {
    color: #535864;
    font-family: "Arial MT";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
    
.card_number {
    color: #8494ab;
    font-family: "Arial MT";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
    
input {
    width: 65px;
    height: 42px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e9ee;
}
    
#validate {
    width: 70px;
    height: 42px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e9ee;
}
    
.validity {
    display: table-caption;
}
    
#holder {
    width: 319px;
    height: 42px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e9ee;
}
    
.btn_pay {
    width: 133px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #005abf;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: linear-gradient
        (to top, rgba(37, 36, 35, 0.18) 0%, rgba(37, 36, 35, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" class="form">
    <div class="form_pay">
        <div class="infopay">
            <p class="info">Информация по оплате:</p>
            <p class="numberpay">Номер счета: 87123658716587</p>
            <p class="sumpay">Сумма платежа: 100 руб.</p>
        </div>
        <h3>Данные банковской карты</h3>
        <div class="datainfo">
            <div class="cart">
                <p class="card_number">Номер карты</p>
                <input type="text">
                <input type="text">
                <input type="text">
                <input type="text">

                <div class="validity">Срок действия
                    <div class="validity_input">
                        <input id="datapicker" type="text">
                        <input id="datepicker" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <input id="holder" type="text" placeholder="Держатель карты">
                </div>
                <div class="cvc">
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <input class="cvc_code" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn_pay" type="submit">Оплатить</button>
</form>

<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Маааленький совет: если у вас в макете нечто шириной 140px и с бордером в 1px, не нужно задавать ширину 138px, достаточно дописать `box-sizing:border-box;` и тогда объект будет занимать те же 140px, и с бордером, и с паддингом.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так, например:

```css
#cards {
  position: relative; 
}

#card1, #card2 { 
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute; 
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius:6px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 130px;
}

#card1 {
  z-index: 10; 
}

#card2 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px; 
}

.digits {
  width: 50px;
}

.owner {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#card2 div.text {
  position:absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 70px;
}

#card2 input {
  position:absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="infopay">
    <p class="info">Информация по оплате:</p>
    <p class="numberpay">Номер счета: 87123658716587</p>
    <p class="sumpay">Сумма платежа: 100 руб.</p>
</div>
<h3>Данные банковской карты</h3>
<div id="cards">
    <div id='card1'>
      <div>Номер карты</div>
      <input class='digits'>
      <input class='digits'>
      <input class='digits'>
      <input class='digits'>
      <div>Срок действия</div>
      <input class='digits'>
      <input class='digits'>
      <input class='owner' placeholder="Держатель карты">
    </div>
    <div id='card2'>
      <div class='text'>CVC</div>
      <input class='digits'>
    </div>
</div>
```

оба блока с `position: absolute` и у них разный `left` и `top`

Comment: то же самое получается

Comment: @lausa не поленился, сделал за Вас

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!!!